# Retrieving Data from DataView C# takes too long

Tags: c#, datatable, parallel-processing, delay, dataview

I have a DataTable named 'dtStocksCriteria'; each cell in it should turn into a process function. So I should traverse all rows and columns.

For this purpose I have Parallel loop on rows. Then I select the Row with this Code:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dtStocksCriteria);
                dv.RowFilter = "xStockCode_FK = " + stock.Code;
```

After that in an Inner Parallel loop I should retrieve each column value with something like this code.

```
val = (double)dv[0]["column name"];
```

This Assignment take about 0.5 seconds which is too long for me. I want to reduce that to approximately 1 millisecond.

I have 398 rows and 110 columns in mt data table, in case that helps.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You don't show the code of your 'parallel' processing. But I bet that there is something wrong there. What are the performances if you don't execute any 'parallel' processing?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot share my code but you can imagine it is just like an foreach . i have use c# parallel like cs.AsParallel().ForAll(s => { some operation });

Comment: Probably this [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176828/why-is-using-asparallel-slower-than-foreach-in-this-case) could be of help. Too few data to gain anything in executing that code in parallel.

Comment: Thanks Steve It was Useful.

Comment: Well, good, if that changed your approach you could post an answer detailing how you resolved the problem. This could be useful for future readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# working with DataView or DataRow or DataTable takes time. 
BUT
If you use `DataRow[int index]` to retrive a cell value it should takes less time than using `DataRow[string ColumnName]` .

SO

When I use 'index' instead of 'ColumnName' it makes my code faster.

BUT

It is still slow because I have too much columns. So the best solution is to reduce the columns count first.